# Deleteing Files Via Inode in Multiple Directories

Tags: linux, directory, delete-file

For a project in my linux class we are required to search through one directory to find the
inodes to remove, then remove them, as well as every file that they have been hard linked to
in three other directories, while some of my classmates wrote down the inodes of the files 
they needed to delete and hunted for them in the other three directories, I was wondering if
 I could do this with one or two commands?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your project for you, just give you a hint:

```
find dirname -inum ###
```

will print the names of all the files with that inode number. Learn more about `find` to figure out how to delete all the files in one command, once you get a list of all the inode numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Inode doesn't know where it's linked from, so exhaustive search of all potential candidates is required.